# Is it possible to highlight certain characters in listbox (c# winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to write a local search program
when users type chars in the textbox, a listbox should list all the possible results.

For example.
if users type "AB"
then listbox displays possible results like:

```
"AB"
"ABDDD"
"ADDDB"
```

i want the charcter 'A' and 'B' to be emphasized, like bold or yellow background
but i can't find the way to give style to certain chars in listbox.
is it possible?
thanx

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556318/how-can-i-implement-incremental-search-on-a-listbox

Comment: @DJKRAZE: it's not really a duplicate. The main thrust of this question is styling parts of a listbox item; that question was not about styling at all, it was about selection of listbox items.

Comment: you should be more specific when asking questions in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible in winforms. Its much easier in WPF. To accomplish this in winforms you need to use `drawitem` event, which is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx). Additionally, [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseListBoxControl_DrawItemtopic) is an example of using it with a `listbox` to change the listbox's appearance.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish exactly what you are looking for in this control: https://advancedlistbox.codeplex.com/. It supports filtering, so you can probably use that to trim the list like you are trying to do.